# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3\cdot 6\cdots(3n)}{7\cdot 10\cdots (3n+4)}x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3\cdot 6\cdots(3n)}{7\cdot 10\cdots (3n+4)}x^n$$
> a) converges for $0<x\le 1$ and diverges for $x>1$
>
> b) converges for all $x>0$
>
> c) converges for $0<x<1/2$, and diverges for $x\ge 1/2$
>
> d) converges for $1/2<x<1$, and diverges for $0<x\le 1/2, x\ge 1$

I calculated radius of convergence of the power series to be $1$.

Hence, The series is convergent for $|x|<1$, and is divergent for $|x|>1$

What should I do next??

Comment: I reformatted this and added $x^n$ in the sum.

Comment: You know it converges if $|x|<1$, so you know it converges on a subset of that interval. This essentially eliminates all but one option.

Comment: How do we know that ther series is convergent at x=1?

Comment: One way to show convergence for $x=1$ is to note the $n$th term is then $O(n^{-4/3})$, because $\frac{3n}{3n+4}\sim\exp(-4/(3n))$.

Comment: $\frac{3n}{3n+4}\sim 1$ @J.G. What did you mean?

Comment: @FShrike That asymptotic relation is also correct, but by being more precise as I was we can compare the series for $x=1$ to something we know converges.

Comment: @J.G. Excuse me - I misinterpreted it as $\exp(-(4/3)n)$ which obviously is not asymptotically similar.

Comment: The series apprers to be $$\frac{3}{7}x + \frac{3\cdot6}{7\cdot10}x^2+\cdots$$ This means it starts at $n=1$, not $n=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should I do next??

You already ruled out b), c) and d), and to confirm a) one has to analyze the behaviour at the radius of convergence.  Due to the limitantion $x>0$ from a) what's left is the case $x=1$.

Behaviour at the radius of convergence does not follow from criteria for the radius of convergence like quotient criterion etc, but it has to be done by hand for  each individual series.

For $x=1$ the partial sums $S_N$ are of the form
$$S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n $$
with
$$\begin{align}
a_n &= \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{3k}{3k+4} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac1{1+c/k} ;\ \qquad  c=4/3\\
&= \exp \ln \prod_{k=1}^n \frac1{1+c/k} \\
&= \exp \left(-\sum_{k=1}^n \ln (1+c/k)\right) \\
&= 1/\exp \sum_{k=1}^n (c/k + O(k^{-2})) \\
&\approx 1/\exp (c\ln n)
= \frac1{n^c} \\
\end{align}$$

Thus, $S_N$ converges because $c>1$.

The last two lines with the Taylor expansion of $\ln$ are a bit hand-waving, but it's not too hard to make it more rigorous.

As an aside, the series converges also for $x=-1$ (and also for all $x\in \Bbb C$ with $|x|\leqslant 1$ for that matter) because it converges for $|x|$.